# Play 2 Scala: Adding a description attribute to this model

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

The following code is from the [Play 2 ScalaTodoList tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTodoList):

**models:**

```
case class Task(id: Long, label: String)

object Task {

  val task = {
    get[Long]("id")~
    get[String]("label") map {
      case id~label => Task(id, label)
    }
  } 

  def all(): List[Task] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("select * from task").as(task *)
  }

  def create(label: String) {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
      SQL("insert into task (label) values ({label})").on(
        'label -> label
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }
```

Now, I'm trying to add a third attribute called **Description**:

```
case class Task(id: Long, label: String, description: String)

object Task {

  val task = {
    get[Long]("id")~
    get[String]("label")~
    get[String]("description") map {
      case id~label~description => Task(id, label, description)
    }
  }
```

(I'm a Scala beginner, not sure if I did it right)

But I'm stuck in `def create` method. How to include `description` to the SQL query?

**EDIT:**

I'm also unsure of how to include `description` here:

```
  def newTask = Action { implicit request =>
    taskForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Task.all(), errors)),
      label => {
        Task.create(label)
        Redirect(routes.Application.tasks)
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, newTask is a `Form[String]`: a form which encapsulates a **single** data, a String.

You need to use a more complex Form to handle both label and description.
You can define a `case class` for these 2 values, or simply use `Tuple`

```
case class TaskForm(label: String, description: Form)
```

In both case, you have at least to modification to do :

** Change the form type in the template :

```
taskForm: Form[String] => taskForm: Form[(String, String)] // with a tuple
```

or

```
taskForm: Form[String] => taskForm: Form[TaskForm] // with the case class defined above
```

** And now, you can retrieve these values in your controller

```
// with tuple
taskForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Task.all(), errors)),
  values => { Task.create(values._1, values._2) .... }
```

or

```
// with case class
taskForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  errors => BadRequest(views.html.index(Task.all(), errors)),
  form => { Task.Create(form.label, form.description) }
```

And of course, you must add a second parameter to Create (or pass the caseclass/tuple object)

```
def create(label: String, description: String) {
   DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
     SQL("insert into task (label, description) values ({label}, {description})").on(
       'label -> label,
       'description -> description
     ).executeUpdate()
   }
 }
```

FYI, `values`, `form` and `errors` are arbitrary variable name. You can choose what you want.

ps : You need to adapt your Form(...) too

Comment: @alexchenco  `values => { Task.create(label, description) }` is not valid. How do you know what is label and description ? Use my exemple : `values => { Task.create(values._1, values._2) .... }`.

Comment: I wrote exactly `values => { Task.create(values._1, values._2) }` and I'm getting `type mismatch; found : Unit required: play.api.mvc.Result` I've seen some examples like this: `errors => BadRequest,
      {
        case (title, dueDate, assignedTo) =>` That would work too?

Comment: And `values => { Task.create(values._1, values._2); Redirect(routes.Application.tasks) }` ? Besides, your syntax is maybe valid (i see this too, but never used).

Comment: Strange, the app runs but when I want to add a task, I get this: `[JdbcSQLException: Column count does not match; SQL statement: insert into task (label, description) values (?), (?) [21002-158]]`

Comment: I don't use Anorm, and it's a different problem => Check the doc first https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaAnorm ;)